# protect from in rush current of buck convertor

Tags: current-limiting, isolation, surge-protection, buck-boost, over-current

I made a PCB base on the following schematic,  [image]
it uses a buck convertor for 12 to  5 v and then uses an LDO for 5 to 3.3 to run my ESP module
I use 2 P-channel MOSFET for polarity protection , but till now burn two set buck converter chips (XP3182) and ESP module
the XP3182 works at a very high frequency and it seems very unstable for input variation. if I connect my USB connection to the ESP module and it does not recognize by my laptop and then if connect the 12v power connection, it burns my buck convertor instantly and highly likely destroys my ESP module whereas polarity protection suppose to protect the ESP

since input power and ESP are not isolated any component problem act like shorted to ground and drawing inrush current and burning the buck convertor
my question is how to protect my MCU from faulty buck convertor and how to diagnose the wrong part

Comment: Can you spend a little more time on your schematic to get it readable and correct? Why do you have a 10uF cap on reset?

Comment: @Kartman the cap delays the ESP boot upon power-up until the internal pullup fills it to 2/3rd vcc or whatever and the ESP starts. this can overcome problems with slow-to-stable PSUs.

Comment: @dandavis the only part that can draw more than 2 amps current is the failure on polarity protection Q1, caz regulator has less than 2 amps

Comment: @Kartman I think the Q1 p-fet may be the reason, it's broken for an unknown reason, and let ground the 5v output of L2 & U2 buck convertor, because there is no other component that can draw the massive current